# How to break nested for loop within an if statement and switch to another statement when other If condition are met?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, break, 8051

I am writing a program for 8051 which uses 2 switch to do two different commands. i.e., When switch 1 is pressed (s1==1), it execute action 1 and when switch 2 is pressed (s2==1), it executes action 2.

What I am trying to achieve here is for example, when action 1 is executing, if switch 2 is pressed, it will break action 1 and execute action 2. The same goes for the opposite case.

Below are my program codes.

```
#define seg P2
#define leds P3
sbit buzzer at P2_7_bit;
sbit s1 at P1_0_bit;
sbit s2 at P1_7_bit;
unsigned char pattern1[]={0x80,0x40,0x20,0x10,0x8,0x4,0x2,0x1};
unsigned char pattern2[]={0x1,0x2,0x4,0x8,0x10,0x20,0x40,0x80};
unsigned char pattern3[]={0x81,0xC3,0xE7,0xFF,0xE7,0xC3,0x81};
unsigned char pattern4[]={0x1,0x3,0x7,0xF,0x1F,0x3F,0x7F,0xFF};
unsigned char pattern5[]={0x99,0x66};
const int t1 = 600;
const int t2 = 150;
int j,k,pb1,pb2;
void main()
{
 seg=0x0;
 leds=0;
 buzzer=0;
 s1=s2=0;
 while(1)
 {
  if(s1==1)
  {
   for(j=0; j<1; j++)
   {
    seg=0x06; delay_ms(t1); seg=0x0; delay_ms(t2);
    seg=0x6F; delay_ms(t1); seg=0x0; delay_ms(t2);
    seg=0x77; delay_ms(t1); seg=0x0; delay_ms(t2);
    seg=0x3F; delay_ms(t1); seg=0x0; delay_ms(t2);
    seg=0x6F; delay_ms(t1); seg=0x0; delay_ms(t2);
    seg=0x39; delay_ms(t1); seg=0x0; delay_ms(t2);
    seg=0x3F; delay_ms(t1); seg=0x0; delay_ms(t2);
    seg=0x3F; delay_ms(t1); seg=0x0; delay_ms(t2);
    seg=0x06; delay_ms(t1); seg=0x0; delay_ms(t2); 
   }
  }

  if(s2==1)
  {
   seg=0x3F;
   for(j=0; j<2; j++)
   {
    for(k=0; k<8; k++)
    {
     leds=pattern1[k]; delay_ms(250);
    }
    buzzer=1; delay_ms(2000);
    buzzer=0;
   }

   for(j=0; j<3; j++)
   {
    for(k=0; k<8; k++)
    {
     leds=pattern2[k]; delay_ms(250);
    }
    buzzer=1; delay_ms(2000);
    buzzer=0;
   }

   for(j=0; j<4; j++)
   {
    for(k=0; k<7; k++)
    {
     leds=pattern3[k]; delay_ms(250);
    }
    buzzer=1; delay_ms(2000);
    buzzer=0;
   }

   for(j=0; j<5; j++)
   {
    for(k=0; k<8; k++)
    {
     leds=pattern4[k]; delay_ms(250);
    }
    buzzer=1; delay_ms(2000);
    buzzer=0;
   }

   for(j=0; j<10; j++)
   {
    for(k=0; k<2; k++)
    {
     leds=pattern5[k]; delay_ms(250);
    }
    buzzer=1; delay_ms(2000);
    buzzer=0;
   }
   seg=0x0;
   leds=0x0;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You're using entirely blocking code, so you'll have to check for the other button in lots of places in each action block (like maybe replace your delay() function with one that checks the other button and returns a state). To avoid that, restructure the code either with threads or cooperative multitasking.

Comment: And what if the two switches are ON ? Which code should be executed ?

Comment: I would rewrite it as a state machine.

Answer (score 0):

suggest

each switch be driving the same external interrupt

when a interrupt occurs reset the interrupt flag so another interrupt from either switch will immediately be responded to.

then determine which switch was pressed (via a couple of GPIO inputs)

One other detail.  be sure to 'debounce' the switch inputs due to switch contact 'chatter' so multiple interrupts are NOT initiated due to a single switch activation.

Then initiate the execution of the function related to that switch.

never exit the interrupt handler function, unless one of the two functions exits

when the interrupt finally exits, then return to the function that was initially interrupted